# Where does code get executed within an application's memory?

Tags: assembly, memory, x86, stack, computer-science

Recently I have been learning x86 assembly code, and I have a few computer science questions.

My current visualization/understanding of application memory is as follows;
[image]

Question 1:

Where does code get executed? I understand that the stack holds and executes functions, but what if your code does not contain any functions. Where within the application's memory is the code (text section) executed?

Question 2:

In my university computer science unit, we learn about the "hack computer architecture", and this architecture had a dedicated memory block for instructions (ROM). Does a modern operating system also implement a similar design? Or is ROM = .text / .data sections.

Comment: The program code is in the text segment.  The stack holds return addresses and automatic variables.  ROM is just memory that is not writable.  On modern systems, the text segment and parts of the data segment (often called rdata or rodata for “read only data”) are mapped read-only, behaving as ROM for the duration of the program's execution.

Comment: Modern machines have Flash ROM for the firmware (BIOS) that runs when the computer boots; you need somewhere for the CPU to load code from immediately after power-on, to get more code+data loaded from disk or network or whatever.  After a modern OS loads and takes over, it usually uses its own drivers for everything, not calling into code in the ROM.

Answer (score 4):

> Where does code get executed?

As others are saying, machine code is loaded from the text segment of the program file into the text segment memory area of the process and from there the processor accesses that memory to run the machine code instruction sequences.

> I understand that the stack holds and executes functions

Not exactly.  When a function is called, it is said to be activated.  When necessary, a function creates a stack frame also sometimes called an activation record.  These hold state (e.g. data not code) for the activated function — memory that the function is working with, but not really "executing".

When one function, A, calls another function, B, then A's execution is suspended, generally using the stack to store the suspended state of A, which will be used upon return from B to A to resume A where it left off.  If B calls C before returning to A, then B will also have an activation record, suspended state for B on the stack, while C executes.  For normal execution, C returns to B, which eventually returns to A.  This stack holds activation records corresponding to the dynamic call chain.

A & B's machine code instruction sequences are in the text segment, regardless of how many times (zero or more) A and B are activated at any point in time.

> what if your code does not contain any functions

It is very hard to get away from functions — `main`, for example, is a function, so in some sense, all C programs start with a function.  Some languages have other constructs, but usually those are supported by a runtime written in a mixture of C/C++ and assembly.

> ... "hack computer architecture", has a dedicated memory block for instructions (ROM) Does modern operating system also implement a similar design?

Modern operating systems, such as unix or windows, use one address space for a process, which has machine code & mutable data separated but stored in the same address space, much like with your picture.  In such a design, you can tell whether an address refers to code or data by its value alone (though in consultation with the address map for the process).

Some embedded processors are similar to `Hack` in having two separate address spaces — one for code and one for data.  In that situation, you have to know which address space a given address refers to, whether code or data, as the value of the address alone doesn't inform on that (the same address can exist twice, once in code and once in data).

The way `Hack` knows is by the usage of the `A` (address) register, which comes from the machine code program — when the program puts a code address into the `A` register, the only sensible subsequent usage is for (eventual) branching (calls, conditional branches, return address capture), whereas when the program puts a data address into the `A` register the only sensible usage is as a data pointer.

(It is up to the machine code program to maintain sensible usages — and having sensible machine code is up to the compiler or assembly programmer, and, this is true regardless of processor and address space(s).)